# On Premise alternative to zeplin.io

Tags: collaboration, graphic-design

In my company I am partially responsible for the Corporate Identity and one of my favorite tools (zeplin.io) won't work because it is subscription payment only, so now I am looking for alternatives to zeplin.io that can be hosted on prem.

After googling for a few hours I only found other cloud only alternatives. The tool can cost money but shall not be subscription based, but I couldn't find anything that matches this, in my opinion, simple requirement. Maybe someone here knows an alternative.

The tool needs to have a few features of zeplin.io, mainly design collaboration, css generation and style guide creation. Everything else in zeplin.io would be awesome bonus.

After the discussion in the comments, here are all features that are vital to me:

- Style export
- Discussions on element level
- In Browser view of design elements that are defined in files uploaded
- Support for PSD or PDF and detect elements

Nice to have features would be:

- Support for Adobe XD
- Upload directly from Photoshop or Adobe XD

Comment: Please specify what you need the tool to do and what features of zeplin.io you specifically need - you cannot expect everybody to know, or take the time to research, a tool just to give you recommendations of alternatives.

Comment: Basically I need a tool for design collaboration.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I actually like someone to answer who had the same issue like me and found a solution.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: @Knerd You are very much limiting the number of people who can answer (those with the same problem who found an alternative) and, of course, those who did may only be happy with their alternative because they don't use the one killer feature that you need. If you list what you need there may be people who know & use exactly the app that you need that never heard of zeplin.io!

Comment: @SteveBarnes I added the vital features and the nice to have ones.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer with a disclosure:

Try Sympli.io, it can be installed on-premises.

Disclosure: I work in Sympli :)

We can set you up without using cloud tools.

We support all the features you stated as vital to you, except the PDF (and more):

Style export - We support color styles, text styles, size and spacings, and you can get all the pre-generated code snippets from the app.

Discussions on element level - Yes

In-Browser view of design elements that are defined in files uploaded - Yes, plus visual difference tool, showing you where and what has changed between versions

Support for PSD or PDF and detect elements - we only support PSD

And we support both Adobe XD and Photoshop and designs can be uploaded directly through plugins.